# How to call image url from directory using php

Tags: php, image, file, url, directory

I want to display the image and the image url of a directory
I found this code, but there is a dot before the filename.

```
<?php
$files = glob("./images/*.*");
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    print "<textarea>";
    print "http://" .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$image;
    print "</textarea>"."<br />";
    echo '<img src="'.$image .'" />'."<br /><br />";    
}
?>
```

the result will be like this :

```
<textarea>http://domain.com./images/filename.png<textarea>
<img src="./images/filename.png" />
```

please help to fix this. thanks.

Comment: Try reading this turorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_directory_readdir.asp

To read files in a directory, you must used the mthod over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the following:

```
<?php
$files = glob("images/*.*");
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    echo '<img src="'.$image .'" />'."<br /><br />";   
    print "<textarea>";
    print "http://" .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$image;
    print "</textarea>"."<br /><br /><br />"; 
}
?>
```